# how to run python file in mongodb using cmd

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a python file named abc.py. I can run it in mongodb with the help of robomongo but i couldnt run it in cmd. Can anyone tell me how to run a .py file in mongodb using cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ensure that your directory is in the correct folder.
for example you can write `cd name_of_folder`

then to run it you need to type`python your_filen_name.py`